# Start MySQL 4.1 without "old-passwords"

Tags: mysql, password

I am having a hard time migrating my MySQL 4.1 database from old 16-byte password hashes to the new 41-byte hashes. The problem is, that the mysqld server automatically starts with the "old-passwords = on" directive, which restricts setting new passwords to 41-bytes length.

My question: Does anyone know how I can tell mysqld to run without the "old-passwords = on" directive? I tried my.ini, commmandline, setting the variable locally, but nothing worked.

Thanks a lot! Philipp

Comment: What OS is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I had to set the flag "old-password=0" in my my.ini config file. It is very important to set this option in the correct section of the ini-file. Section names seem to correspond with windows service names: In my case, the windows service name is "MySQL4" - unfortunately this section had to be manually created, as the default name after setup seems to be "mysqld". All the best!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked in /etc/my.cnf or /var/lib/mysql/my.cnf, maybe is is set there? BTW, the directive is old_passwords (underscore, not dash)

Comment: I found out that I had to set the flag "old-password=0" in my my.ini config file. It is very important to set this option in the correct section of the ini-file. Section names seem to correspond with windows service names: In my case, the windows service name is "MySQL4" - unfortunately this section had to be manually created, as the default name after setup seems to be "mysqld". All the best!

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking this is a Windows box -
Just edit my.ini and set 
"old_passwords=0"
Or comment/delete the line that sets old_passwords

Comment: I found out that I had to set the flag "old-password=0" in my my.ini config file. It is very important to set this option in the correct section of the ini-file. Section names seem to correspond with windows service names: In my case, the windows service name is "MySQL4" - unfortunately this section had to be manually created, as the default name after setup seems to be "mysqld". All the best!